# How to add alphabetic sections in TableView from database using swift 3

Tags: ios, database, uitableview, swift3

I'v created a TableView that shows data from my database, now I want to add alphabetic sections into my table my database already sorted alphabetically.

My problems:

1 - I can't make the Dictionary to accesses only the first column of the database (the name column).

2 - I don't know how to get the first letter of the names and store every item in the letter the name start with.

If you know a better way than using a Dictionary I'm open to any suggestions.

My code:

```
class crimesTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var marrCrimesData : NSMutableArray!

@IBOutlet weak var crimesTableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.getCrimesData()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func getCrimesData()
{
    marrCrimesData = NSMutableArray()
    marrCrimesData = ModelManager.getInstance().getAllCrimesData()
    crimesTableView.reloadData()
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return marrCrimesData.count
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: crimesTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! crimesTableViewCell
    let crime: CrimesInfo = marrCrimesData.object(at: indexPath.row) as! CrimesInfo
    cell.nameLabel.text = crime.Name
    cell.detailLabel.text = crime.Detail
    cell.timeLabel.text = crime.Time


    return cell
}
```